# How can I escape the '@' character in ERB?

Tags: ruby, string, erb

I am generating a Perl answer file using an
[*Embedded Ruby code*](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)
(ERB) template. This answer file contains variables which are then used to invoke an installer in silent mode.

I have no control over the installer code; what I do have control over is the answer file.

The installer throws an expected warning if the string contain unescaped metacharacters.

I want the answer file to have a Perl string constant containing the escape character. This value is fed using embedded Ruby code.

I have two variables. One is defined in Ruby and the other in Perl.

```
my $variable = <%= [@var].flatten %>;
```

`$variable` is in Perl and `@var` is Ruby.

`@var` will contain email addresses.

```
@var = "abcd@gmail.com"
```

I want to escape the at `@` character so that Perl 
does not consider `@gmail` to be a variable.

In short, I want to write `"abcd\@gmail.com"` to the answer file.

I tried multiple things but in vain.

```
@var = "abcd@gmail.com"
@var.gsub("@", "\@") # => "abcd@gmail.com"
@var.gsub("@", "\\@") # => "abcd\\@gmail.com"
@var.gsub("@", "\\\@") # => "abcd\\@gmail.com"
```

Comment: So you're generating Perl code using Ruby?

Comment: What is `[@var].flatten` supposed to do?

Comment: Yes. I am generating Perl code using Ruby. This perl code is an answer file/response file to facilitate silent installation.

Comment: '@var' is an instance variable and can be a string or an array.
  [@var].flatten  is used to achieve two things:
  1) [@var] will covert string to array.
  2) if '@var' is an array, then .flatten method will create a flattened one dimentional array instead of array of an array caused as a result of [@var]

Comment: What is your expected result, i.e. how should the Perl code look like?

Answer (score 4):

`@var.gsub("@", "\\@")` is correct. Ruby is representing the result as the equivalent double-quoted string which requires the backslash to be escaped

Try `puts @var`

Comment: I did that and it is not working. In all the scenarios, the perl variable stores: "abcd@gmail.com" which in turn gives me abcd.com as @gmail is not defined(empty) in perl context.

Comment: As a workaround for now, i have substituted @var with [at] 
    @var.gsub("@", "[at]")
And in the perl code i am replacing [at] with \@:
$var =~ s/\[at\]/\\\@/g;

Comment: @Rajneeta: You need to explain fully how your string is used in Ruby and Perl. It sounds like you have multiple unescaping going on (are you using backticks or `system`?) so try `@var.gsub("@", "\\\\@")` and take a look at [`String::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote)

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect specific use case and scenario.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of an ***MCVE***. Please take a look at [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The idea is that you publish a short program that we can run ourselves and see the symptoms. It shouldn't be at all difficult given that you already have most of the pieces in place.

Comment: @Rajneeta: Really, please spend the few minutes it will take to post an example Ruby program and the corresponding ERB so that we can see this for ourselves. I have Ruby and Perl installed here and am quite willing to spend a few seconds re-learning the corners of the language that I have forgotten; I imagine there are many people like me. I asked you for this an hour ago, and if you had made the effort then I am certain that you would have had an answer long before now.